# Windows file association to open with Eclipse/CDT editor

Tags: eclipse-cdt

How can I open a file with Eclipse/CDT when I double click it in windows explorer?

I set the file association in windoes to eclipsec.exe and it opened Eclipse/CDT, but not the file.

If Eclipse is open, it says "Workspace in use..."

Ideas?

mcb

Answer (score 1):

this Might be what you are looking for

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/OpenFileFeature

Answer (score 0):

This article may be somewhat helpful, it talks about associating content types with specific editors:

http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3648736/Eclipse-Tip-Define-Custom-Content-Types-to-Identify-Your-Data-Files.htm

In addition, an [Eclipse book on Google Books gives instructions on associating file types.][2]

[Also, see this](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/eclipse/platform/doc/isv/3.3.0-v20070621/isv-3.3.0-v20070621.jar!/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_core_runtime_contentTypes.html).

[2]: http://books.google.com/books?id=6Ob1ANNVcXcC&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=how+to+associate+a+file+extension+with+eclipse&source=bl&ots=jlFv9NRjyt&sig=OrWkd8nvLFVXuM5SWexG2uWeAHM&hl=en&ei=_GTWSqePBtPTlAf85JWjBg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=14&ved=0CDwQ6AEwDQ#v=onepage&q=how to associate a file extension with eclipse&f=false

Answer (score 0):

Associate the file type with eclipse.exe, not eclipsec.exe.

1. If the file type is not already associated with an application then you can choose the application by double-clicking the file, otherwise you will need to open the "Set Associations" app from control panel.
   a. In Windows 7 this is done via the "Default Programs" item in "Control Panel".
   b. Inside that item there's an option labeled "Associate a file type... with a program".
   c. Look for the filetype, in my case I looked for .java. Select it and click "Change program..." in the upper right.
2. From there click "Browse..." and find eclipse.exe, not eclipse**c**.exe, in your filesystem, select it and click ok.
3. Now when you double-click the file it will be opened in eclipse regardless of whether eclipse is already open.

Comment: I expanded my answer with directions for Windows 7. Can you elaborate on what problem you are experiencing? This has worked for me on multiple computers.

Comment: Anyone else find Windows 7 just ignores your selection of eclipse.exe and only allows eclipsec.exe to be selected?

Comment: @faintsignal Yes on Windows 7 I can't select eclipse.exe anymore. This started happening for me once I upgraded to eclipse neon. Any help anyone ??

Comment: @faintsignal @abdelrahman-sinno
Just have a look in the registry, you have to add the correct path in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\eclipse.exe\shell\open\command` I recently had to change `%USERPROFILE%\eclipse\java-2021-03\eclipse\eclipse.exe" "%1` to `%USERPROFILE%\eclipse\java-2021-09\eclipse\eclipse.exe" "%1`